# Accessing same Array and/or File across 4 different classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I just had a question for a program that I am creating. So to provide background, I am creating a program using the GUI creator on eclipse. So the program involves creating a list of Employee objects (Employee is a separate class) and managing that list, easy enough. I am using a List to store the various Employee objects. Now here is where the issue arrives. I need to access this List across 4 different classes in my project folder so I thought about modifying the constructors of each class to accept a List as parameter. But then I would have to initialize the list within the constructor to a new list erasing any data each time. So my next solution was appending to a file each time and just reading from there. But where the issue arises is when I would need to access this File across 4 different classes. This program will be made on my computer and used on many different computers for testing purposes. So i would like to ask, is there any way I can be able to append to/read from the same file from all 4 different classes and also to what directory will the file be created on the different computers since I won't be able to point the file to be created in a specific directory? I hope this isn't too vague and I can always clarify if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is due by Friday. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to just create the list in your main class and then pass it to the other classes. Can you elaborate a bit on the structure of your program and what your classes do.

Comment: ahh sorry,So one class is called Employee, which has all the privates such as firstName, lastName, getter methods and setter methods,etc. The next class is called Employ where my entire GUI is initialized and run and where my List of Employee objects currently are. This is where all my windows/buttons/JFrame etc are. The 3rd and 4th classes are called SearchFrame and PrintFrame. They both extend JFrame and I create instances of both objects in my employ class to display the Jframe that searches through the list and prints from the list. But I need to access the List from the last 2 classes.

Comment: How do I pass it on to the other classes, is it through some getter/setter that this is done?

Comment: Sure you could have a setter for the list in each of your other classes and set it from the main class whenever you call the other classes. You could make your list static and have a static getter method in the main class that you call within your other classes. There are plenty of ways to do this without an external file.

Comment: But the reason i would need an external file anyways is because after I close the program, the list of Employee's have to save, without writing externally, the data would be lost upon the termination of the program. And also this program will be boxed into a jar file when it is done and tested across 5 different computers. I cannot  create a File object to point to some directory because I have no clue where the file will be written so how would i create that file and read from it and write to it without knowing its location. Thanks again for your help Odin.

Comment: In that case yes you should use a file to save the contents, but it would still be better to use a list during run-time and only read the file on opening the program/write it on closing so that your code doesn't have to constantly access the file system.

Comment: Yes I like your idea I will use only the List runtime. But do you know how to create and write to this file and read from it without its location being unknown. Is there any set methods that can fetch the file to write then flush then read later when I reopen it. Im sorry, I just do not know how to go about that last part. Thanks again